# How does the stylesheet_link_tag :all work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I want to include some stylesheets in my rails application via

but it doesn't work as expected. It creates the line

But I want to include all the file in app/assets/stylesheets, especially the twitter bootstrap files located there...

How do I do it? I literally don't have any clue and the post I found don't help me either... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way of including the stylesheets is not recommended now. If you are using Rails >= 3.x, it is better to enable assets pipeline and add the line in your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
*= require_tree
```

This will include all the stylesheets under app/assets/stylesheets/* even the styles under directories and then do this in your html file.

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will still have to enable the pipeline, which will have to wait until this evening. I'll let you know once I got it to work :)

Comment: Hmm I actually had it enabled the whole time. It says "undefined method `stylesheet_include_tag' for #<#<Class:0xb35fabc8>:0xa5596dc>". Weird. I have Rails 3.2.8 and rake rails:update only tells me that routes.rb is not fine, but I think I can ignore that. Any idea where there could be something fishy?

Comment: Sorry! it should be stylesheet_link_tag

Comment: I think my whole rails is messed up, it just doesn't work... I'll let you know once I fixed everything.

Comment: Ok it works now. I just needed to run rake assets:clean. Thank God it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `*= require_tree .` in application.css